# Combine the fields definitions through "import *"

Tags: django

Combine the fields definitions through "import *"

There are definitions of field in /models and /forms

[django/db/**init**.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/__init__.py)

```
__all__ = [
    'AutoField', 'BLANK_CHOICE_DASH', 'BigAutoField', 'BigIntegerField',
    'BinaryField', 'BooleanField', 'CharField', 'CommaSeparatedIntegerField',
    'DateField', 'DateTimeField', 'DecimalField', 'DurationField',
    ...
   ]
```

[django/forms/fields.py at master · django/django](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/fields.py)

```
__all__ = (
    'Field', 'CharField', 'IntegerField',
    'DateField', 'TimeField', 'DateTimeField', 'DurationField',
    'RegexField', 'EmailField', 'FileField', 'ImageField', 'URLField',
    'BooleanField', 'NullBooleanField', 'ChoiceField', 'MultipleChoiceField',
  ...
    )
```

I wonder if it's possible to combine the fields definations through "import *",
What's the instinct difference between them?

Comment: I don't understand your question. These are two completely different things: the first list is model fields, the second list is form fields. What are you asking?

Comment: I don't understand either. can you describe more? What exactly you want to know? you want to import * from `django.db` or `django.forms`?

Comment: Thank you, I just confuse about the form in Django.@DanielRoseman

Comment: I'm reading more docs @seuling